# Represent data in non-contiguous buffers with Memory<T>

Tags: c#, memory

According to this [article](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2207031/Writing-High-Performance-Code-Using-SpanT-and-MemoryT-in-C) the `Memory<T>` struct can be useful to represent non-contiguous buffers as a contiguous buffer however it doesn't go into detail nor can I find any way to do so.  I'm trying to write some code to communicate over sockets.  I want to write my classes to expose `Memory<T>` to hopefully give flexibility in optimizing allocation down the road.  If there was a neat and tidy way to create a contiguous buffer view from `Memory<T>` I would use it otherwise I will have to fall back to passing `IList<ArraySegment<byte>>` even though this method lacks `CancellationToken`

Comment: Possibly you should switch to pipelines. See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/)

Comment: I believe the article is wrong or worded poorly. `Memory<T>` has to represent contiguous memory, however, it can represent different chunks of that contiguous memory by shifting the pointer location. But I've never seen a usage of `Memory<T>` that can take non-contiguous segments and represent them as a single buffer without copying to a new buffer.

Comment: @GuruStron  Looking into pipelines I have 2 questions.  Is this well served for protocols where a fixed sized header and message whose length is in header (thats how my protocol works), seems that this extra abstraction would only be worth the cost when the protocol is more dynamic, Secondly I cant find examples of it being used to transmit to a socket.  Everything seems to point to it only being used on the socket receive side

Comment: @MDK can you please share some code? Also as far as I understand one of the reason of the pipelines introduction is the reading of messages with dynamic length.